# Number of files shown via Properties and when copying are different?

Tags: filesystem, files

I have looked at "Properties" of a folder to see the number of files and the folder's size. When I decided to copy the folder to my Desktop, number of files and the folder's size shown on the progress bar are different. What is the meaning of this? Please see the screenshots for a better understanding.

[Number of files shown via Properties (5167 items):
[image: Number of files shown via Properties]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJxgQ.png)

[Number of files shown while copying (copying file 970 of 26910):
[image: Number of files shown while copying]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiVXj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the folder properties, the displayed number will not contain hidden files.

In Unix/Linux dotfiles refers to files/directories with a dot (`.`) prepended to their name (i.e. `.bashrc`). The leading dot is used as an indicator to not list these files normally but only when they are specifically requested like pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Nautilus or typing `ls -a` on a terminal. This is because, generally, dotfiles are generally used to store configurations for different applications, for example Mozilla creates a .mozilla folder on your home directory which contains their configuration files as well as browser cache.

When you copy a folder you'll copy it with dotfiles included.

It's recommended to backup dotfiles, as they stores some important data (as your Firefox bookmarks, your Thunderbird downloaded mail, the emblems of foldes and files... and so on.

Comment: Thanks. But I think this behavior is kind of misleading because there is a huge size difference when excluding hidden files.

Comment: Yes, but these files are into the folder, and will be copied. I'd recommend to copy them, as them stores some important data (see the edit made to my answer).

Comment: Not all the data is important (e.g. often you don;t need what is in `~/.cache`), but is idea to copy everything if you have time and space.

Comment: Well, if you tell the copy command to copy everything, that's what it's gonna do. As for the dot files, if you don't care about your personal settings , you may let them be. Copy the files with Ctrl+A (select all , done only to visible items), and Ctrl+V in the directory where you want it.  But if you don't wanna go over and over on "How did I set that PS1 prompt in bash again? " then copy those dot files !